# Show no available downloads when array value is empty or non existent

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to create a simple list of pdfs with an if else statement, where the pdfs are shown as normal when there are pdfs present, and when there are none it needs to show: no available downloads.

Now it always shows that message no matter what (when there are no pdf files, and when there are pdf files).

I tried everything now and nothing is working.

When there is no id present or id is empty it needs to show the message, but only when there are no pdf files at all.

What I tried so far:

```
 <?
//pdf bestanden
$pdf                = "SELECT * FROM `snm_attachments` WHERE parent_id = '".$conn->real_escape_string($contentcr[0]['id'])."'";
$pdfcon             = $conn->query($pdf);
$pdfcr              = array();
while ($pdfcr[]     = $pdfcon->fetch_array());


foreach($pdfcr as $pdf){
    if(isset($pdf['id']) && !empty($pdf['id'])){ 
        $downloads .= '<li><a href="cms/attachments/article/'.$contentcr[0]['id'].'/'.$pdf['filename'].' "target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>'.$pdf['filename'].'</a></li>';   
    }else{
        $downloads .= '<li>No available downloads</li>';
    }

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($pdfcr).'</pre>';
}

echo $downloads;
?>
```

I also tried this:

```
<?
//pdf bestanden
$pdf                = "SELECT * FROM `snm_attachments` WHERE parent_id = '".$conn->real_escape_string($contentcr[0]['id'])."'";
$pdfcon             = $conn->query($pdf);
$pdfcr              = array();
while ($pdfcr[]     = $pdfcon->fetch_array());

if(count($pdfcr) > 0) {
  foreach($pdfcr as $pdf){
    if($pdf['id'] != ''){
        $downloads .= '<li><a href="cms/attachments/article/'.$contentcr[0]['id'].'/'.$pdf['filename'].' "target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>'.$pdf['filename'].'</a></li>';   
    }
  }
}else{
    $downloads .= 'leeg';
}
echo $downloads;
?>
```

The above doesn't even display the message, it displays nothing when there are no pdfs present. When I echo the PDF id on a page without pdfs it doesn't show anything, but it also doesn't show the no downloads available message.

How can I achieve this? It can't be that hard yet it is taking me hours to do this.

How it is now (see how it still shows the message, even when there are two pdfs):

[image]

Correct behaviour:

[image]

Here is the output of print_r($pdfcr) 
https://kobra.io/#/e/-KIgRDOAz_Ki2PpOKTU5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding and empty value of last fetch function. This is correct way:

```
$downloads = '';
while ($pdf= $pdfcon->fetch_array()) {
        $downloads .= '<li><a href="cms/attachments/article/'.$contentcr[0]['id'].'/'.$pdf['filename'].' "target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>'.$pdf['filename'].'</a></li>';   
}

if ($downloads) echo $downloads; else echo 'No data';
```

Comment: This worked, it makes sense but the only thing I don't understand is how it adds an empty value?

Comment: Because when you reach all records, `fetch` returns FALSE value and you put this value into array with your old code. In my code, first is checked conditions then pushed value. In your code you first push value then check condition ;)